# Input element pattern attribute not behaving as regex

Tags: javascript, regex, html, forms, validation

I have an input that I'm trying to validate using a pattern attribute, but it's not working as a standard regular expression. How are these things handled differently?

See: http://jsfiddle.net/danwoods/yf7rnop1

I'm adding code here because it's required by StackOverflow; for a working example of the issue, please see the fiddle:

```
<input type="text" required pattern="\s?-?[0-9]+.?[0-9]*\s?,\s?-?[0-9]+.?[0-9]\s?" value="39.75323, -104.99197" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

> The pattern must match the entire value, not just some subset.

You're missing a `*` after the last `[0-9]` so the pattern does not match the entire string.